# Can we change the question that shows up in /about?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

As of now, the question that shows up on https://anime.stackexchange.com/about is this one: [What are the added values of ecchi to a series?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5836/what-are-the-added-values-of-ecchi-to-a-series). This is an alright question, but I don't know that it necessarily is the question we would want to be the "face" of the site, so to speak.

Do you suppose it might be better to change that question to something more mainstream, like a question on Naruto or FMA or a trope or something? (I recall reading somewhere that mods have the ability to change which question that shows up there; if not, never mind this.)

Comment: We can only change the introduction part above the "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions" part.

Comment: @Krazer You obviously know better than I do, but [this post by a mod on CSTheory](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2676/suggestions-for-our-about-page) claims that mods can edit the question that is displayed. Or is that because they're graduated and we aren't or something?

Comment: My bad. I just noticed that option.

Comment: The current available options are the ecchi one and the [DBGT](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/361/was-dragon-ball-gt-made-by-fans) one.

Comment: For reference, the criteria for a question to be available are [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163947/what-determines-the-questions-available-for-selection-in-the-about-page). Basically, it needs to be short and have at least 2 short answers, one of which is accepted. Also no "crazy formatting".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, and seems like the community agrees with you.

I've reverted it back to the original question, [How involved was Akira Toriyama in the production of Dragon Ball GT?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/361/was-dragon-ball-gt-made-by-fans).