# Some crude numbers on user retention across SE (which may not be a useful metric at all)

Tags: discussion

In drafting an answer to [the mod question about user retention](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2537/), I wrote up a quick query to examine one crude measure of user retention across SE sites: http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/351067/. See the description for details.

By this measure, our user retention is in the gutter, sitting at just under 10%. This is the 12th-worst out of all SE sites. Note, though, that there are many confounding factors (e.g. sites that were founded between 6 and 12 months ago will be inherently skewed; the import of Rus.SE confuses matters; Patents.SE is a special case; etc.).

I don't know if this is a useful metric (it basically tells us that we get a buttload of one-and-done ID-req askers), but the numbers are there if you want to look at them.

Comment: There are many factors at play here and I don't think they should be dumped on id-requesters without evidence.

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko Come on, man. The evidence is there for everyone to see. http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/351089. If we subtract these schmoes out of the numbers, retention (by this measure) spikes to ~16%, which is solidly middle-of-the-road.

Comment: I wasn't saying they weren't gonna be a contributor, you just  blamed them without backing it up so for all we knew it could have been wrong. Thanks for the query though.

Comment: Subtract the ID requests though and you cut the number of questions  roughly in half. Taking the site from from barely meeting one of the two current requirements for graduation (10 questions a day) to not even being close. I don't think percentage retained is a good metric of site health. If we assume having more people stick around will result in a better quality site than a better metric would be the absolute number of retained users. It's not clear that banning ID requests would increase the actual number of users that stick around and contribute to the site.

Comment: @RossRidge Sure, I pretty much agree with you. However, I'll go one step further and argue that absolute number of retained users isn't even that useful either. All said and done, we don't really care about _users_  - we care about _content_. Of course, content is produced by users, so measuring user participation isn't wholly unrelated to measuring content generation, but I think the measures are far enough apart that we can't really infer much about one based on the other.

Comment: Interestingly Arqade has a similar rate, and they're doing pretty well (imo at least)

Comment: I have to agree that this isn't a very useful metric. I've seen users stick around the site for a while who (frankly) I would really rather left, since they produce a steady stream of lousy posts that get downvoted or closed, and won't get the hint when the community offers advice on improving their content.

Comment: If this means we get alot of casual users, that is good.  If it means they are creating a new account each time with a temporary email, that is neutral (to me).  If it means they aren't coming back because we offend them and/or ignore/close their questions, this metric implies something very bad.  Banning ID requests might discourage users (note: I'm biased as I came here first for an ID request.)