# 2016 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

As an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation, we will once again be holding a Q&A with the candidates in connection with the moderator elections.  Participation is completely voluntary.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3914/2016-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

Here's how it'll work:

- During the nomination phase, (so, until Monday, August 29th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at current.
- At the end of the phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. That said, if I have concerns about any questions in this fashion, I will be sure to point this out in comments before the decision making time.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Comment: Question: the election page says "if there are 10 or fewer candidates, we skip directly to the election phase." I think there's a real chance we won't have 11 candidates by the end of the week. If that's the case, do the questions we post here still get answered or is that considered part of the primary?

Comment: @Torisuda i asked this [on chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31876232#31876232) last night and from the responses i got (both being mods either here or elsewhere) even if we skip the questions still get asked.

Answer (score 12):

Quite a lot of the activity on the site is concentrated around just a few shows: mainly Naruto, Bleach, One Piece, Dragon Ball, and Death Note. While these are all fine shows, they hardly showcase the diversity of anime, and don't leave a lot for people who aren't fans of long-running action/adventure.

What's your take on this situation? Is it fine as it is, or should the community strive for more diversity of topics—more shoujo, more older anime, more artsy/experimental material like *Aku no Hana* and *Goodnight, Punpun*? If you support more diversity, what steps would you take as a moderator to make it happen?

Answer (score 8):

Edit: This question has been changed to be more specific now that we have [an issue-list meta post](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3903/lets-take-a-look-back-at-our-site-policies-2016-edition).

Last year we [asked the community](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2564/1530) about things they wanted to be clarified or fixed about our policies on Anime & Manga. This helped myself as the newly elected mod highlight some topics for review.

One year on and [a new meta post later](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3903/lets-take-a-look-back-at-our-site-policies-2016-edition) , Is there any particular policy the site currently has that you feel needs to be changed, or reviewed?

Answer (score 7):

Some Stack Exchange moderators are activists—they take a strong leading role in the community, bringing up issues, guiding discussions, suggesting policy, and creating initiatives. Others are more passive; they let other members of the community shape policy, enforce it less stringently, and wait in the wings for exceptional situations that require their unique abilities.

The passive approach fits more with Stack Exchange's description of moderators as "glorified janitors" and "human exception handlers" as laid out in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) and other posts. However, activist moderators can be good for a site; they can help unite and guide a user base, and can ensure that a valid concern brought up by a significant minority of the community gets a fair hearing and doesn't get automatically ignored in favor of the majority view.

As a moderator, would you be more of an activist, or would you take a more passive approach? Why? How would you recognize a situation that would benefit more from the opposite approach, and how would you deal with it?

Answer (score 6):

***NOTE: should this question get in the top 8 question this should only be selected as a question if the number of candidates is less than 8 ([number of candidates from last year](http://www.opavote.org/results/6186483249577984/0))***

This year we have only had # Candidates nominated to join the mod team while last year there was 8 candidates. can you see any sort of barrier that would prevent other users from applying to become a part of the mod team in the next election?

- if so in what way do you think we as a community can overcome this barrier?
- if not what are your opinions as to why so few nominated to become a mod this time?

Answer (score 5):

Last Year we had problems with Identification Requests with what should be done with them being asked of the candidates in [last year's mod election](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2537/1587).

With the topic now dead, buried, covered in concrete and without a spoon to eat it's way out is there another outstanding [single] subject that you think the community needs to address? why does this subject need to be addressed?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 4):

we have [a number of community events](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2682/1587) from annual events like [Conspiracy Santa](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2684/1587) to one off events like [EU A&M Meet up](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2692/1587).

Are there any other Events you would like to see occur to help bolster community cohesion, attract more users to the site and/or increase activity and participation on the site?

Answer (score 2):

What's your opinion on Taisho posting images in site's main chatroom?

Taisho's image posting did got criticized in the past for being unnecessary or for not being safe for office. So what you think in favor or against it?

Comment: also please consider the safeness of visiting a recreational site's chat room while at work :p

Comment: @Hakase Other site don't frequently share girl pick with big privates ;) so other  site's chat room are bit more safe for office use.

Comment: This is a v good question. A lot of other SE users see this and run away.

Comment: Isn't that a good thing @ToshinouKyouko? ;D

Answer (score 1):

What additional value would you add to the existing moderator team?